After Upgrade Magento version from 2.3.5 to 2.4.7, an error in the Admin Grid(Custom module) started to appear
After a magento update was made from version 2.3.5 to 2.4.7, an error in my custom module started appearing in the administrator. In the main view inside the administrator shows me the following error:

Type Error occurred when creating object: G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid\Collection\Interceptor, G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::__construct(): Argument #5 ($connection) must be of type ?Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface, string given, called in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
Exception in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131

Collection.php

namespace G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
  protected $_idFieldName = 'slide_id';

  public function _construct()
  {
    $this->_init('G4A\MainSlider\Model\MainSlider\Grid', 'G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid');
  }

}

di.xml
<type name='Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory'>
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="infra_main_slider_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">infra_main_slider</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

Code(constructor)generated by magento:
generated/code/G4A/MainSlider/Model/ResourceModel/MainSlider/Collection/Interceptor.php

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy, \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager, ?\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null, ?\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null)
    {
        $this->___init();
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }

Magento version 2.4.7 
PHP 8.3 
MariaDB 11.4.3
when bin/magento di:compile command is executed the error is shown
when bin/magento setup:upgrade command is executed the error isn't shown
The store is in developer mode
Any help is appreciated...

Solution
Collection.php

namespace G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends SearchResult
{
  protected $_idFieldName = 'slide_id';

  /**
   * Initialize dependencies.
   *
   * @param EntityFactory $entityFactory
   * @param Logger $logger
   * @param FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy
   * @param EventManager $eventManager
   * @param string $mainTable
   * @param string $resourceModel
   */
  public function __construct(
    EntityFactory $entityFactory,
    Logger $logger,
    FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
    EventManager $eventManager,
    $mainTable = 'infra_main_slider',
    $resourceModel = null,
  ) {
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
  }
}


In Magento 2.4.x, there were some changes in the constructor signatures and how collections are handled, particularly with UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult used for grids.
Steps to Fix the Issue:
Step 1: Update the Collection Class
Your Collection class extends Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult, which means that the constructor parameters need to match the updated signature in Magento 2.4.x.
Here’s how you can update your Collection class constructor:
namespace G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult;

class Collection extends SearchResult
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'slide_id';

    /**
     * Collection constructor.
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        ?\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        ?\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }
}

Step 2: Update di.xml
In your di.xml, you’re defining a virtualType for your custom collection class. Since you are extending SearchResult, Magento automatically manages the database connection and other dependencies. Therefore, ensure the definition matches Magento’s expectations.
Your di.xml seems mostly fine, but ensure it looks like this:
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="infra_main_slider_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<virtualType name="G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">infra_main_slider</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

Step 3: Clear Cache and Recompile
After making these changes, follow these steps to refresh the Magento environment:

Clear Cache:
php bin/magento cache:flush


Run Dependency Injection Compilation:
php bin/magento setup:di:compile


Deploy Static Content (if in production mode):
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f


Reindex (optional but recommended):
php bin/magento indexer:reindex



Step 4: Verify

Test the Admin Grid to ensure that the custom module’s admin grid now works without throwing any errors.

Confirm that the new constructor in the Collection class correctly initializes the required dependencies and the grid displays as expected.


Summary:

The error you're encountering is due to type mismatches in the constructor parameters after upgrading Magento.
The primary fix is ensuring that your custom Collection class constructor matches the expected constructor for classes extending SearchResult in Magento 2.4.x.
After updating the constructor and di.xml, clear cache, recompile, and test the Admin Grid.


Thanks for the reply, but after tried your code answer, compile command throws the following error:
Errors during compilation: G4A\MainSlider\Model\ResourceModel\MainSlider\Grid\Collection
Incompatible argument type: Required type: string.
Actual type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
File:
/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/app/code/G4A/MainSlider/Model/ResourceModel/MainSlider/Grid/Collection.php

It should work, Or you might need to change the di.xml as well as the grid collection,
